# Consuming elements from queue with blocking processing in some cases

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, queue, c++14

I have one thread that pushes to the queue and one that consumes elements from the queue.
Processing of one of the elements is asynchronous but I do not want to process other elements during this one is processing.
(Let's assume that output stream and queue is thread safe)

I wonder what is the best way to implement consuming thread... I think while(true) and conditions is not the best choice.

Is it simple implementation (`process2` has to be ansynchronous).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

std::atomic_bool isProcess2Processing{false};

void process0()
{
    std::cout << "process0" << std::endl;
}

void process1()
{
    std::cout << "process1" << std::endl;
}

void process2()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, []() { isProcess2Processing = true; std::cout << "start process2" << std::endl; while (std::rand() > 10000) {}; std::cout << "finished proces2" << std::endl; isProcess2Processing = false; });
}

void consume(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        process0();
    }
    else if (x == 1)
    {
        process1();
    }
    else
    {
        process2();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> q;

    std::thread consumingThread([&q]() {
        while (true) {
            if (!q.empty() && !isProcess2Processing) {
                consume(q.front());
                q.pop();
            }
        }
    });

    while (true)
    {
        q.push(std::rand() % 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply run `process2` in `consumingThread` (without create new thread). and nothing else can run at same time.

Comment: No, process2 must be asynchronous - I cannot change it. My code is only a demo. I have to use asynchronous calls in `process2`.

Comment: you can always wait for it.

Comment: What control do you have over `process2`? Can you have it return a `future` that the caller may then wait on? Or notify a condition variable at the end?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder what is the best way to implement consuming thread... I think
>   while(true) and conditions is not the best choice.

Your contemplation here is justified: The biggest problem with using a while-loop like this (i.e. without any *waiting* involved) is that you are wasting CPU time and power. Your secondary thread (and per the code given your main thread too) keeps a CPU core all to itself for some time for no apparent reason, so that other tasks cannot get CPU time for themselves.

The most naive way of going about changing that is adding [some kind of `sleep`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) like here:

```
std::thread consumingThread([&q]() {
    while (true) {
        if (!q.empty() && !isProcess2Processing) {
            consume(q.front());
            q.pop();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
});
```

Here you'll be sleeping for 5ms during which the scheduler will be able to let other tasks do their work.

A few things in addition you should make sure to have are exit condition for each loop and also call `consumingThread.join();` before you leave `main()`.